# Send Keyboard Outputs

Tags: java, exception, import, awt

I wanted to create a keyboard output API type thing so that I could make a machine learning program for Tetris, and I tried:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Keyboard
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Robot keyboard = new Robot();
        keyboard.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);

    }

}
```

but it has an error for `new Robot()`, it says "Unhandled exception: java.awt.AWTException". and it has an error on the line after that: "Cannot resolve symbol 'KeyEvent'", even though I have `import java.awt.*;`. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Star-imports do not import "subpackages" (as those dont technically exist). And the `KeyEvent` class is in `java.awt.event.KeyEvent`. So it is not covered by your import. Regarding your `new Robot`, this is a checked exception. So you have to either try-catch it or add declare `throws`. Thats a rather basic issue that you can easily solve by just reading a tutorial about exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

let's check what errors we getting.

`Unhandled exception: java.awt.AWTException`

This is means you don't handle an exception thrown from calling constructor `new Robot();`
you need to check this in documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html
or use your IDE its can show which exception can be thrown.
To fix this we need to surround constructor call `new Robot ();` with try-catch block
or declare an exception throw in a method main();
more about exceptions here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

`Cannot resolve symbol 'KeyEvent'`

Its can means you missing some imports in your case you imported import `java.awt.*`; but this import does not include `java.awt.event`

```
//Don't use static (*) import just import what you need in this case
//or use your IDE auto import

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.AWTException;

 public class MainClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Robot rob = new Robot();
        // Robot can throw an AWTException
        // we need surround him with try-catch block
        // Or declare exception throw in current method

        // Pressing button
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);

        // Releasing button in case if we don't do that key may stay in press state
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // Process exception if something go wrong
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Zabuza better?

Comment: @Zabuza: yes, better, 1+

Comment: what happens if I leave catch blank, like
`try
        {
            Robot keyboard = new Robot();
            keyboard.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);

        }
        catch ( AWTException e )
        {


        }`
sorry for formatting it won't let me do new lines right in the comment

Comment: @Nightmare FNaF  its fine but if execution has been thrown  you don't see message in your console. I really recommend use e.printStackTrace(); its let you see what happened in your code and where it happened (line number , method etc..)